# Java Enum access to private instance variable

Tags: java, enums

Consider the example:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    VALUE1("value1"),
    VALUE2("value2"),
    VALUE3("value3")
    ;
    private String value;

    private SomeEnum(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    //toString
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

How come can we do this (and the value **really** changes)?

```
SomeEnum.VALUE1.value = "Value4";
System.out.println(SomeEnum.VALUE1);
```

Isn't that enum instance(s) are implicitly *static* and *final*? Also, since `value` is `private`, why can I access it outside other classes?

Comment: Oh! By the way, this question is a question on some code I saw, the code that I'm maintaining.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No-one seems to have addressed the private aspect. My guess is that you're accessing the private field from a containing type - that your enum is *actually* a nested type, like this:

```
class Test
{
    static void Main() {
        // Entirely valid
        SomeEnum.VALUE1.value = "x";
    }

    enum SomeEnum {
        VALUE1("value1");

        private String value;

        private SomeEnum(final String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

That's entirely legitimate and normal - you can *always* access private members of a nested type from the containing type.

If you make the enum a top-level type, you won't see this.

As for changing values - as everyone else has said, `VALUE1` is implicitly static and final, but that doesn't stop you from changing `VALUE1.value`. Again, this is entirely in accordance with how Java works elsewhere - if you have a static field of type `List`, you can still add entries to it, because that's not modifying the *field* itself.

If you want to make `SomeEnum` properly immutable, make the `value` field `final`.

Comment: That just gives a perspective of `An enum type is a type whose fields consist of a fixed set of constants`. I can have a mutable property inside an enum and change it at any time in my own leisure.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman: Yes, you can - and that's a really bad idea. An enum type is a type with a fixed set of *instances* of that type. So there's a set of static final fields within type `SomeEnum`, which are fields *of type* `SomeEnum`. Those are used to access the instances. Any extra fields that *you declare* work exactly like other fields - you can have static fields or instance fields, final fields or non-final fields etc.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I maintain codes that do just that and I thought that it can't be since it breaks `enum` contracts (or I thought it does).

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman: It's not clear what you mean - the `enum` contract in the JLS certainly doesn't guarantee that the instances will be immutable. I would *strongly* recommend that you make them immutable though.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman: So your enums aren't just mutable, but are *being mutated*? If so, that sounds like code which really needs to be addressed ASAP.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do

```
SomeEnum.VALUE1 = "Value4";
System.out.println(SomeEnum.VALUE1);
```

but you can do

```
SomeEnum.VALUE1.value = "Value4";
System.out.println(SomeEnum.VALUE1);
```

and `value` really changes, but not the *static final* **VALUE1**.

> Also, since value is private, why can I access it outside other classes?

You can access a private field in an outer/inner class, but I cannot find an example of where you can access it from another class (in the same package for example).

Comment: Sorry, just updated the question: It's `SomeEnum.VALUE1.value = "Value4";

Comment: Good answer. In other words, final provides only shallow immutability.

Comment: similar to `static` only makes the reference static, `volatile` only make the reference volatile, `transient` only makes the reference transient (but not the object referenced) `private`/`public` only makes the reference private/public but not the contents. etc. etc. ;)

Comment: True, but shouldn't I not be able to see `value` since it's private? I.e. I shouldn't be able to say, `VALUE1.value` at all (unless, I had a public getter method).

Comment: Can you give an example of where you are accessing from another class (and not an outer or inner class)

Comment: The person who wrote the example, later `removed` the `private` keyword. `value` is now default (and hence why he could see it outside other classes). This was a stupid exercise.

Answer (score 2):

> *Isn't that enum instance(s) are implicitly static and final?*

Nope. Members of enum-instances such as `value` in your example can be mutable.

(The references to the instances (`SomeEnum.VALUE1` etc in your example) are final and static though.

> *Also, since value is private, why can I access it outside other classes?*

You can't. An `enum` is a "class" with an enumerable number of instances. That's all.

`VALUE1` is in this case a an instance of the "class" `SomeEnum`, thus `SomeEnum.VALUE1.value` is an ordinary field like any other.

---

When you do

```
System.out.println(SomeEnum.VALUE1);
```

you invoke `SomeEnum.VALUE1.toString` which accesses the `value` field. You're not accessing the `value`-field immediately.

```
// Not possible since field is private.
System.out.println(SomeEnum.VALUE1.value);
```

Comment: Sorry, just updated the question: It's `SomeEnum.VALUE1.value = "Value4";

Comment: You can view `value` outside other classes. I did a test case and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't that enum instance(s) are implicitly *static* and *final*?

The Enum instances have these traits. But no one said, these instances are *immutable* like `Integer` or `String`. So you can modify the values.

That does not mean that this is recommended practice! It isn't.

**Edit**

To explain a little more:

"Enum implicitly static" means:

```
enum Foo { FOO };
```

Here `FOO` is static, although the *normal* Java syntax would suggest, that `FOO` is an instance variable wrongly named like a constant. You also access it like a static variable.

"Enum implicitly final" means:

```
enum Foo { FOO, BAR };
Foo.FOO = Foo.BAR;
```

is not allowed. The *reference* stored in `FOO` cannot be changed. You also cannot create new *instances*.

"Enum *not* implicitly immutable" means: `Foo.FOO` will give you an object. A standard object. If the object allows modifications of its own content - so it be. This is not forbidden.

Comment: That's **not** what I asked at all. Consider changing the answer before it gets downvoted.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman: Looks like what you asked to me, unless I'm not seeing the edit...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, my question is not about modifying `VALUE1` but why `VALUE1.value` can be modified at all, even though it's a private instance. Doesn't the enum rules (of implicit `static` and `final`) apply to its instances too?

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman: Can you explain a little bit? Besides the wording I'm in the same ballpark as the other answers _and_ your own observations. I simply stated, that the traits you mentioned are not relevant to your problem, it's the (missing) immutable trait that's linked to your problem.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman: You mean its fields (there's no such concept as a "private instance"), and no, certainly not. There's no transitive application of the `final` modifier *anywhere* in Java.

Comment: @JonSkeet: No, there was no edit you could miss at that point of time.

Comment: @A.H.: Okay, in that case it seems you did indeed answer exactly what was asked, and it's just the OP misunderstanding what it means for an enum value to be final.

Answer (score 1):

The enums itself (`VALUE1`, `VALUE2` and `VALUE3`) are static and final. They are three instances of the `SomeEnum` type and we can't change them (like deleting `VALUE1` from the enum or adding a `VALUE4` at runtime).

But we can add public fields to the instances (like in your example) and alter the content of those fields at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

SomeEnum.VALUE1 = "Value4" ... actually does not work.

More important, VALUE1 will always only be equal to VALUE1 and not VALUE2 or VALUE3, independent of it's member value.

Comment: Look at my question **carefully**. I said `SomeEnum.VALUE1.value = "Value4"`, not `SomeEnum.VALUE1 = "Value4"`.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman: You did now, yes - but what did your question say *before* you updated it?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I updated my question 21 minutes ago. The OP answered 12 minutes ago. That is 9 minutes difference since my last update (of which I included the change).

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman: Do you not think it's possible that the answerer had your original question open all that time? I think it's entirely possible - and that if you originally made a mistake in the question, and others are trying to help you, then it's nice to give them the benefit of the doubt. Your comment should have at least suggested that the answerer might have only seen the (incorrect) original version of your question. Between this and "Consider changing the answer before it gets downvoted" it feels like you're not really in the spirit of things...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, thanks. I assumed the OP just opened the question now since 9 minutes is long enough to see an updated change. I will consider being more user-friendly on posts.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman: Consider a user who opens up SO, finds a bunch of questions and puts them in different tabs, then looks at each one in turn. Although there's notification of answers being added, I'm not sure there's notification of the question being updated...