# How would I use enum on my project?

Tags: java, enums, ejb, enumeration

I have a class with an instance field lockAction, value 1 is lock and 3 is unlock. I'd like to introduce enum on to my EJB project. How do I got about that?

```
public enum lockUnlock {
    LOCK, //1
    UNLOCK, //3
```

}

Comment: suppose this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464939/java-enum-access-to-private-instance-variable) propose a better solution

Comment: Oracle's [enum tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) has an example of a value-containing enum type.

Comment: But you're currently not giving us enough information about whether you need to wrap the integer value into the enum (e.g for backwards compatibility etc) or if you could just use a simple enum.

Answer (score 3):

```
you can use something like this.

public enum lockUnlock {
    LOCK(1), UNLOCK(3);
    int value;

    lockUnlock(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        lockUnlock[] b = lockUnlock.values();
        for (lockUnlock b1 : b) {
            System.out.println(b1 + "........" + b1.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could assign a value to the enum like so.

```
public enum LockUnlock  {
    LOCK(1), UNLOCK(3);

    private final int value;
    private LockUnlock(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() { return value; }
}
```

Comment: @SteveSmith How else could it be done? Of course, the enum has ordinals, but those values would be 0 and 1.

Comment: Should this be a method or class? How would it call it in my EJB?

Answer (score 0):

@eldix_ you can use enums when you know that some of the Constant data in your code can't be changed by the user. 
For example.
if you want to show some data in a drop down on the screen like below

[image]

as shown in the example, where the drop down values are constants, which client has to select.

we can change this at one place use it any where, without data being changed.
[image]